# Azure function to Bulk Delete records from cosmos Db

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I plan to execute (after an Azure data factory pipeline) a Bulk delete of some records from Cosmos Db container giving specific fields criteria.
The way that I want to run the Azure function is trough an HTTPS trigger but I don't know if it's feasible to run a bulk delete, If yes...do you have a kind of example???

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to do a bulk delete or truncate on a Cosmos container. Typically the way most people do this today is to delete and then recreate the container. That avoids the RU/s cost of deleting every item.

Comment: The .net SDK has bulk support on v3 and v2 has a seperate bulk executor library with BulkDelete in preview.

Comment: Yes but I find that most people are looking for a truncate command rather than this.