# Cleanup Cosmos collection by document type

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection (1B records) and I need to clean it up

Schema:

```
// <pk> - item Id
// <type> - literal enum, e.g. Type1|Type2|Type3

{
  "partKey": "<pk>",
  "type": "<type>"
}
```

I need to delete all documents where type = `Type2`.

1. I can't execute `DELETE ... WHERE c.type = 'Type2'` as it is not supported
2. I can't execute [Stored Procedure](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/bulkDelete.js) as the collection is partitioned
3. I'd prefer not to use SDK

What is the best way to cleanup the collection by the specified condition?

Comment: `I'd prefer not to use SDK` - Curious to know the reason behind this.

Comment: This task looks like Ops and first of all, I'm trying to find an Ops solution (tool, MS service, ability to launch the query, etc). SDK is something I'd prefer to use at the very end

Comment: If you're looking for a tool to do this, may I request you to look at [`Cerebrata`](https://cerebrata.com/products/cerulean/features/azure-cosmos-db/sql-api). It has this feature where you can delete documents in bulk by specifying a query. So you would ask Cerebrata to delete the documents that matches a query like `Select * from Root r where r.type = 'Type2'`. It will fetch the matching documents and delete them. [Disclosure: I am one of the devs who built this tool].

Comment: thank you. this looks like exactly what I was looking for, but I'm limited with proprietary software, so I'm looking for something more common/MS or opensource

Comment: I am not aware of any open source/MS tool that would do that. Back to SDK I guess. Do let me know if you would be interested in knowing the approach you will need to take if you were to code this.

Comment: @deeptowncitizen Azure Data Factory can achieve this. Do you mind using that?

Comment: @SteveZhao it looks like it is not supported: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64806362/azure-function-to-bulk-delete-records-from-cosmos-db

Answer (score 1):

I create the following data for test in my collection:

```
[
    {
        "partKey": "1",
        "type": "1"
    },
    {
        "partKey": "5",
        "type": "4"
    },
    {
        "partKey": "2",
        "type": "2"
    },
    {
        "partKey": "3",
        "type": "2"
    },
    {
        "partKey": "4",
        "type": "2"
    }
]
```

Then create a dataflow in ADF. Both source and sink dataset is your Cosmos DB collection.

1. Check Include system columns option in Source setting.

[image]

2.Create Alter Row transformation to delete documents.

[image]

3. Check Allow delete option and type your Partition key.
   [image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Please let me know whether it is helpful to you. If no, I will delete it later.

Comment: thank you. this solution looks really great. eventually, I'll not be able to use it because of corporate subscription constraints